# iPhone stuck at Apple bootup after attempted evasi0n deletion

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I have an iPhone  5c, I have it jailbroken, and I was trying to take it off. So, stupidly, I went into iFile and started  deleting anything I saw about evasi0n, Cydia, or any tweaks I had installed.

I'm guessing it was a big mistake, because now my iPhone:

A. Is stuck at the bootup and

B. Won't connect to a computer.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Can you put your device in Recovery Mode?

Comment: For your information, and for others that might end up here, there isn't a safe way to hot-remove a jailbreak like that. The only safe way is to restore it in iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

Put your device into DFU mode following these instructions:

1. Connect the iPhone to your computer and open iTunes
2. Hold the power and home buttons for ten seconds
3. Release the power button but keep on holding the power button
4. iTunes should pop up saying that it detected an iPhone in Recovery Mode. At this point, the screen should be black. If you see anything, start over
5. Restore the iPhone

You should never delete jailbreak files. They are essential to your device. The only official way to remove your jailbreak is to backup files and then restore.

Comment: DFU is not Recovery Mode, these 2 are different!

Comment: I know. DFU mode just has more options once you enter it.

Comment: iTunes always says recovery mode. I suggest you read here from more info: http://www.tuaw.com/2011/05/25/iphone-101-what-is-dfu-mode-and-whats-the-difference-from-rec/